# Github- Get changes of open source public repository in private repository

Tags: git, github

I have a private Github repository wherein I have pushed code of some open source Github repository and I am doing some customizations in it. Now if there are some changes or fixes in the public repository I want it in my private repository also.

I had checked to fork public repository in my private repository but in that everyone publicly comes to know who has forked their repository which I don't want.

Can someone please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `everyone publicly comes to know who has forked their repository which I don't want` Would you care to elaborate why? You are making it sound like you want to use the work of someone else without giving credit to the original author.